# scale up logo in splash screen flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, splash-screen

I want to scale up the logo when the duration passes using the scale animation and then the second screen shows up

```
    return AnimatedSplashScreen(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        splashIconSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        splash: Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Image.asset(
                  'Assets/Animation.gif',
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.5,
                ),
                SizedBox(height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.02,),
                Image.asset(
                  'Assets/text.png',
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.7,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        
        animationDuration: Duration(seconds: 3),
        pageTransitionType: PageTransitionType.scale,
        nextScreen: Login(),
    );
  }
}
```

there should be alignment but I couldn't find where to add the parameter

Comment: A quick scan of the package try `splashTransition: SplashTransition.scaleTransition,`

Comment: I want the out animation not the in animation

Comment: you could use `ScaleTransition` and control when it starts.